# Robot Simulator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

All,

I am trying to work on a simple solution in JS.

[image]

I have a program that currently prints out a direction of a simple simulation. But what am seeking to do is to currently embed the x and y coordinates as it loops through.

For example:

1. If for example, I have a string code like "LLRAA". This is what it means, Start your index facing "North" with {x,y} = {0,0}. So during the loop, when I see L: Move Left=West and the second character, L is Left: move to South and sees R= Move Right = West. Now at West, if it sees A, it means decrement x coordinate by 1, so the coordinates will be {-1,0} and still stand at West. For the next iteration, A decrease x by -1 so it will be {-2,0}.

So final output is {"x: " + x + " y:" + " bearing:" + d} = {x:-2, y:0, bearing:West}

My code is below for testing:

```js
function robotSimulator(param){

    let counter = 0;
    let d = "";
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;

    //Using this too see if the direction for the bearing is a clockwise movement or anticlockwise one
    for(let i=0; i < param.length; i++){
        if(param[0] == "\n"){
            return null;
        }

        else if(param[i] == 'L'){
            counter--;
        }
        else if(param[i] == 'R'){
            counter++;
        }
        // console.log(counter);

     //If count is positive, then it means it is moving clockwise direction
    if(counter > 0){
        if(counter % 4 == 0){
            d = "North";
        }
        else if(counter % 4 == 1){
            d = "East";
        }
        else if(counter % 4 == 2){
            d = "South";
        }
        else if(counter % 4 == 3){
            d = "West";
       }      
    }
    
    //If count is negative that means the direction is anticlockwise
    if(counter < 0){
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
                d = "North";
            else if (counter % 4 == -1)
                d = "West";
            else if (counter % 4 == -2)
                d = "South";
            else if (counter % 4 == -3)
                d = "East";
    }
    }
    
    
    return d;
    return ("x:  "+ x + "  y:" + y);
}

console.log(robotSimulator("RRLLL"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to decouple the robot movement from its rules.
Specifically, you could define the rules (which encodes state transitions) in an object, i.e. how the state of the robot changes, given some instruction.
The for-loop part (here, I use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the final robot state) can be reserved for iterating over each instruction in the string and computing the robot's new state.

IMO by having the state transition logic in a separate object, it can make it easier to refactor when/if you want your robot to support new instructions.

```js
function robotSimulator(param) {

  if (param.length === 0 || param[0] === "\n") {
    return null;
  }
  
  // each direction has a name, and also defines how to move.
  const directions = [
    { name: "North", move: ({ x, y }) => ({ x, y: y - 1 })},
    { name: "East", move: ({ x, y }) => ({ x: x + 1, y })},
    { name: "South", move: ({ x, y }) => ({ x, y: y + 1 })},
    { name: "West", move: ({ x, y }) => ({ x: x - 1, y })},
 ];
 
  const numDirections = directions.length;
  
  // normalise direction (`counter` in your exampl using negative indexing.
  const normaliseDirection = (d) => d >= 0 
    ? d % numDirections
    : numDirections - Math.abs(d % numDirections);
  
  // each command maps to a function that updates the current state.
  // state is an object of x, y (position) and direction (`counter` in your example).
  // as you add more instructions for your robot, you can update this object
  // as required.
  const applyMove = {
    "L": ({ x, y, d }) => ({ x, y, d: normaliseDirection(d - 1) }),
    "R": ({ x, y, d }) => ({ x, y, d: normaliseDirection(d + 1) }),
    "A": ({ x, y, d }) => {
      const { x: newX, y: newY } = directions[d].move({ x, y });
      return { x: newX, y: newY, d: normaliseDirection(d) };
    },
  };
  
  // loop through each instruction, update state using `applyMove`,
  // and return the updated state.
  
  const initialState = {
    x: 0, y: 0, d: 0,
  };
  
  const finalState = Array.from(param).reduce((currState, action) => {
    if (!(action in applyMove)) {
      // handle error
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: '${action}'`);
    }
  
    return applyMove[action](currState);
  }, initialState);
  
  const { x, y, d } = finalState;
  
  // lookup name of final direction
  return { x, y, direction: directions[d].name };
}

// {x: -2, y: 0, direction: West}
console.log(robotSimulator("LLRAA"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works for you:-

```
function robotSimulator(param) {

    let counter = 0;
    let d = "";
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;

    //Using this too see if the direction for the bearing is a clockwise movement or anticlockwise one
    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        if (param[0] == "\n") {
            return null;
        }

        else if (param[i] == 'L') {
            counter--;
        }
        else if (param[i] == 'R') {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (param[i] == 'A') {
            x--;
        }

        //If count is positive, then it means it is moving clockwise direction
        if (counter > 0) {
            if (counter % 4 == 0) {
                d = "North";
            }
            else if (counter % 4 == 1) {
                d = "East";
            }
            else if (counter % 4 == 2) {
                d = "South";
            }
            else if (counter % 4 == 3) {
                d = "West";
            }
        }

        //If count is negative that means the direction is anticlockwise
        if (counter < 0) {
            if (counter % 4 == 0)
                d = "North";
            else if (counter % 4 == -1)
                d = "West";
            else if (counter % 4 == -2)
                d = "South";
            else if (counter % 4 == -3)
                d = "East";
        }
    }


    return `{x: ${x}, y: ${y}, bearing: ${d}}`
}

console.log(robotSimulator("LLRAA"));
```

Comment: Well the syntax for "A" being x-- will not work.

Comment: Kindly check the image and see, the current facing direction on the cardinal point will determine if the x or y value will decrease or increase.